# Android payment library

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I know there is in-app billing, but is there any way to transfer money back to client?
For example on his paypal account? 
Or client can only make payments and not receive them?

Comment: You want to refund the amount? I think this is possible in Paypal. You can try with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can refund a purchase, an the money goes back to the client's Google Checkout account (usually backed by a credit card). Anything besides this is out of the scope of the Android Market/Play payment system. You can certainly use PayPal or bank transfer, or even a check to give anyone money :)